# Visualizar las tabla existente que hay en una base de datos sql en un Combo Box

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando  en un ComboBox  mostrar las tablas que tengo en mi base de datos sql  el error es que me muestra en el ComboBox este mensaje  :
**System.datadatarowview**

```
String consulta = ("select * from sys.tables");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consulta, cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);

        Notificaciones_Consulta.DataSource = dtRecord;
```

Me podrían ayudar no encuentro la razón.

Gracias,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si es un combobox en `winforms` debes asignar las propiedades `DisplayMember` y `ValueMember` indicando que columna quieres visualizar

```
Notificaciones_Consulta.DisplayMember = "nombrecol";
Notificaciones_Consulta.ValueMember = "nombrecol";
Notificaciones_Consulta.DataSource = dtRecord;
```